Do you really need input bias current cancellation resistors?
The below article is taken from TI's the Signal e-book.The article number is 10 page no 14.
In this the author says the reason for not using Rb and it is given below.


Thermal noise produced by Rb and possible external noise pickup at this high-impedance node may be additional reasons to eliminate Rb. With minimal error from the input bias current, why add possible noise to the circuit?

I understand the thermal noise concept.
How does Rb create a high impedance node?


How Rb create a high impedance node?

The non-inverting input is the node that they allude to.
In the TI schematics in your question, the  "high impedance" node is only 7.5 kΩ but, it could be higher if Rb needed to be higher (should R1 and R2 be higher in value).

Do you really need input bias current cancellation resistors?

They used to be quite commonplace (60s, 70s and 80s) but, these days we have FET input amplifiers that have small bias currents compared to devices that use BJTs hence, fewer applications require them.

Thank you.But Opamp input impedance is very high compared to 7.5K.So that non inverting input with or without 7.5K is a high impedance node.

@Confused the input impedance is in parallel to Rb hence, the node impedance is $R_{IN} || R_b$. In other words, the node impedance can be regarded as being Rb.

Isn't it the non-inverting input they allude to?

@AnalogKid do'h.... fixing.... thanks.
